# Can imacros clear ALL history, cache and cookies?

Tags: cookies, imacros

Is there a way to clear all cache and cookies (equivalent of pressing `ctrl`+`shift`+`del` in firefox and selecting every checkbox) using imacros?

I know about the `CLEAR` command but I have found that it doesn't clear everything. Thank you.